# hasClass doesn't work in my js code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use `hasClass` in the following code, but that doesn't work for me, please see my demo in jsfiddle and tell me, what do I do wrong?

```
<span>
    <input type="text" name="relation" class="IdRelation">
</span>
​

if ($('span').hasClass('IdRelation')) {
  alert("ok");
}​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Bwkv/)

Comment: It kind of looks like you're using `IdRelation` as a unique marker (obviously just a guess based on your markup). If so you might want to consider using `id="relation"` instead and select it using `$("#relation")`.

Comment: Especially with the prefix `Id` which does not sound like it would be a class

Comment: there is no `span` with a class `IdRelation`, did you mean `input`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution

The class is on the `<span>` child, an `<input>`, so add it in the jQuery selector : `$('span input')`.

```
if ($('span input').hasClass('IdRelation')) {
  alert('ok');
}​
```

Try the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dQ7fV/).

## A bit of explanation

Accorting to jQuery documentation, `$('span input')` is a [**descendant selector**](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector) :

> Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.

You could also use `$('span > input')`. It is a [**child selector**](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) :

> Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

Both are good in your situation, because the `input` is a direct child of the `<span>`.

If your code was :

```
<div>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="relation" class="IdRelation">
    </form>
</div>
```

The solution will be `$('div input')` or `$('div > form > input')`.

Comment: You might want to emphasize that you added `input` to the selector string - it's not immediately obvious that it's different at all.

Answer (score 11):

It is not the `<span>` element that exposes the `IdRelation` class, but its `<input>` child. Try:

```
if ($("span input").hasClass("IdRelation")) {
    alert("ok");
}​
```

Or maybe, depending on your actual markup:

```
if ($("span > input").hasClass("IdRelation")) {
    alert("ok");
}​
```

The selector in the first code snippet will match all `<input>` elements that are [descendants](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/descendantselector) of a `<span>` element, whereas the selector in the second snippet will match all `<input>` elements that are [direct children](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector) of a `<span>` element. Both will match the `<input>` element in your sample markup.