# How to use jQuery hasClass in complicated variant ( nested divs)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to add some image background if my input has class valid.

I read documentation, read some stackoveflow questions ( like this -> [hasClass doesn't work in my js code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669222/hasclass-doesnt-work-in-my-js-code) ), but I'm failing to implement it in my modal.

Here is jsfiddle with all HTML and js -> http://jsfiddle.net/33PGQ/34/

Can someone suggest what is wrong ?

P.S.Also tried to write in hasClass function like this: div > form > ...( did not work )

Comment: Your selector should be: `$('.modal .form_for_login form .field2 input')` because modal and form_for_login are class attributes, not tags

Comment: Using `console.log()` once in a while can be very revealing. It's certainly more effective than wildly trying all kinds of selectors, hoping that things suddenly start to work. ;)

Comment: Thanks. One more thing - how to check it asynchronically: not only onload - should I add setInterval function or there is better variant ?

Comment: Why not add an image background to your input with css based on the class valid?

Comment: mmm, it is jQuery validation. It is not static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not `hasClass` method, you selector is *wrong*, you should use `.` for class selectors, jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors.

```
$('.modal .form_for_login form .field2  input');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q7jw5/

Comment: One more thing - how to check it asynchronically: not only onload - should I add setInterval function or there is better variant ?

Comment: @MID You can add listeners for change event. `$('.modal .form_for_login form .field2  input').change(function(){...})`

Comment: I want to check inputs on all forms , but this code not working. I will post in another comment.

Comment: $('input').change(function(){
  if ($('input').hasClass('valid')) {
  alert('vaild');
  }
  if ($('input').hasClass('error')) {
  alert('error');
  }

})

Comment: @MID Try replacing 'input' with `this`-> `$(this).hasClass('valid')`

Comment: $('input').change(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('valid')) {
  alert('vaild');
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {
  alert('error');
  }

})                          not working

Comment: Do you get OK, because I don't get any alert in your jsfiddle(

Comment: @MID Yes, I get, try changing value of the input.

Comment: oh, sorry. I thaught it is observing attribute changing. I mean it is calling when class is changing)Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong. jQuery selectors, as with CSS selectors, use a period to indicate a class name:

```
<div class="abc">
$('.abc')
```

So this will fix your fiddle

```
if ($('.modal .form_for_login form .field2 input').hasClass('valid')) {
```

Comment: Thanks) My variant is easier))

Comment: One more thing - how to check it asynchronically: not only onload - should I add setInterval function or there is better variant ?

Answer (score 0):

Accidently found answer:

```
  http://jsfiddle.net/33PGQ/35/
```